# How to allow client to not ignore SOAP Port with "-extension" tag

Tags: web-services, soap, console, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to consume a Web Service running in localhost that has this WSDL "http://localhost:8000/eamsLink/RepositoryService/?wsdl".

I ran the command:

```
wsimport -keep -p ws -verbose -wsdllocation http://localhost:8000/eamsLink/RepositoryService/?wsdl http://localhost:8000/eamsLink/RepositoryService/?wsdl
```

Console Output:

```
parsing WSDL...


[WARNING] unknown extensibility element or attribute "EndpointReference" (in namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing")
  line 1 of http://localhost:8000/eamsLink/RepositoryService/?wsdl

[WARNING] Ignoring SOAP port "NetTcpBinding_IRemoteSource": it uses non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding.
You must specify the "-extension" option to use this binding.
  line 1 of http://localhost:8000/eamsLink/RepositoryService/?wsdl

[WARNING] Service "RemoteSourceService" does not contain any usable ports. try running wsimport with -extension switch.
  line 1 of http://localhost:8000/eamsLink/RepositoryService/?wsdl


Generating code...
```

It loads a huge number of classes but it does not create any "Service" class.

Do you know how to handle that error?